# Pass Bitmap from one Activity to another

Tags: android, android-activity, bitmap, textview

I tried to convert a TextView into Bitmap and I tried to pass it to another Activity on a single Button click.

My code is:

**Activity sending the Bitmap :**

```
 save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        View view0 = txt1.getRootView();  //txt1 is a TextView
        view0.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view0.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bmp0 = Bitmap.createBitmap(view0.getDrawingCache());
        Intent in = new Intent(Meme_make.this,S_meme.class);
        in.putExtra("bm0" , bmp0);
        startActivity(in);
 }
```

Activity Receiving the Bitmap :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sm);
    main1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Bitmap bitmap = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bm0");
    main1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

But when I click on the button , the activity is automatically closing and taking me back to the Main launcher Activity.

How to do this without any issues ?

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
in.putExtra("bm0" , bmp0);
```

and

```
Bitmap bitmap = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bmp0");
```

In particular bm0 vs bmp0, you may just be missing a p.
But in general I would also cast your retrieved bitmap to a bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bmp0");
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake while copying the code to the question , now I have edited my question . There is no mistake with the name of the Bitmap string , but still I cannot pass that bitmap to another class

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet.
Send bitmap

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityName.class);
intent.putExtra("Bitmap", bitmap);
```

Retrieve Bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Bitmap");
```